$X$ is complete iff for any sequence of closed subsets $X_n$ with $X_{n+1}\subset X_n$ and $\textrm{diam}(X_n)\to 0$, $X_n$ have a common point
This is an exercise from "A course in metric geometry" by Burago & Burago & Ivanov (page 11).

Excercise 1.5.4. The diameter of a set $S$ in a metric space is defined by $\textrm{diam}(S) = \sup_{x,y\in S}|xy|$. Prove that a metric space $X$ is complete if and only if it possesses the following property. If $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of closed subsets of $X$ such that $X_{n+1}\subset X_n$ for all $n$, and $\textrm{diam}(X_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, then the sets $X_n$ have a common point. Show that the assumption $\textrm{diam}(X_n)\to0$ is essential.

(emphasis mine, and $|xy|$ is a distance between $x,y$)
I have solved the former part of the problem, but I am not sure about the latter part (the emphasized part). What exactly am I supposed to show here?
Am I asked to find a metric space that is incomplete but satisfies the property without the assumption that $\textrm{diam}(X_n)\to 0$? Given the proposition in the exercise, I think such a metric space cannot exist. If a metric space satisfies the property without the assumption $\textrm{diam}(X_n)\to 0$, then it would also satisfy the property WITH the assumption, so it would be complete.

You should have used the assumption $\textrm{diam}(X_n) \to 0$ to produce the point in your proof in part 1, otherwise your proof is incorrect. So it doesn't follow that there would be a common point without that assumption.

@ZoeAllen Do you mean that just using the assumption $\textrm{diam}(X_n)\to 0$ in the proof is enough to address that it is essential?

@ZoeAllen What I meant here is that if "any sequence of closed subsets ${X_n}$ with $X_{n+1}\subset X_n$ has a common point" is true then clearly "any sequence of closed subsets ${X_n}$ with $X_{n+1}\subset X_n$ and $\textrm{diam}(X_n)\to 0$ has a common point" is also true because the former statement states more general thing.

@ZoeAllen You're right. Sorry for bothering.

@Kaira yes, sorry, there is no issue with that statement. The issue is that completeness doesn't imply all sequences of nested closed subsets have a common point.

@Kaira my first comment was just saying that just because completeness implies a common point in sequences with the diameter condition doesn't mean that completeness implies a common point in sequences without the diameter condition.

You need to show that in a complete metric space it may be the case that a sequence of nested closed spaces does not have a common point. Hint: think about closed subsets of the real line with infinite diameter.

Another hint: your proof for the first part should have used the diameter condition to show that a sequence of points taken from each set has a limit. Can you think of a sequence of nested closed sets so that there's no way to choose a point from each and get a limit? I.e. that every point eventually ends up outside the sequence of sets.
